# MDT: workgroup installs?

Tags: mdt-2010, windows-7

Im trying to use MDT to capture and reproduce a win7 image with some customizations (extra SW). Ive tried both the 'scripts\litetouch.vbs' process and the 'litetouchpe_x64.iso' (pxe boot) approach. Neither seems to get very far.

Im wondering if the issue is that my MDT machine is a domain member whereas the system Im trying to image isn't (and needs to remain a workgroup member). I can get to the 'scripts' folder on the MDT system only if I use a domain login / pw. It appears to start some process but never does anything (no error messages, either)

The PXE boot process seems to take my domain login info, then it reboots but it reboots to the original OS and no 'imaging' takes place.

Am I going down the wrong path from the get-go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible to create a non domain joined system from a domain joined MDT instance. I do it fairly regularly for XP and 2008R2 systems. I don't use it for 7 all that often.

It sounds like the OS installation process isn't running for some reason from your MDT server. I have inadvertently moved or deleted items within the task sequence that caused this behavior.

Try creating a new totally stock task sequence using the same base OS WIM file and go from there. If that doesn't do it there is likely something wrong with your base image.